# unable to connect to business network on cloud

Tags: ibm-cloud, blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I'm trying to import my blockchain business network on cloud 
using IBM bluemix
I already have all the dockers up and accessed the composer playground on cloud successfully, imported my bna file successfully, imported my admin card successfully.
But when I try to connect to the network I get the error below.

> Error: Error trying login and get user Context. Error: Error trying to
>   enroll user or load channel configuration. Error: Enrollment failed
>   with errors [[{"code":400,"message":"Authorization failure"}]]

I also tried to create a new card using playground directly and gave it admin privileges but I got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The error means that Composer attempted to enrol the specified identity against the Fabric CA. This identity is not registered with the Fabric CA, so you get the authorization error.  Firstly, you can review the docker logs of your CA server to see errors eg. `docker logs ca.org1.example.com` to get info on the auth failure.

Its possible you tried to connect with a card with no credentials set (certificate/key, not enrol id + secret). You say you 'accessed playground on cloud successfully' (I assume you mean connected to your business network that you deployed (ie rather than imported) - as 'admin' - or some other 'network admin', is that correct?

When you issue an identity, (say, connected as an admin to the biz network), add it to your wallet in Playground, then switch identity (use now) to that id. This activates the identity. Next go to 'My business networks' and connect as that identity card - it will have credentials set in your local wallet (depending on where you're connecting from - local playground or playground inside your Bluemix environment). If you return to the 'My Business Networks' you can use the 'export' icon - alongside "that user's" business network card and save it to disk (with credentials) as a .card file. That card is the one you would share,  to connect to Playground elsewhere as that identity. If you continue to have issues I would remove the cards in question using `composer card delete` (having exported it first) from your wallet location and import the exported .card (ie with credentials set) again, then try connect from Playground.